# AVMutableComposition to merge videos, but have no sound

Tags: ios, xcode, video, avfoundation

I've been trying to get this to work, i've got 3 videos and i'm trying to merge them, but once i've merged them, the final video has no sound.. i've been looking around and apparently i have to add the audio separate aswell but i'm unsure how to do this.

```
-(void) mergeVideos {
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
AVURLAsset* firstAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:delegate.videoURL1 options:nil];
AVURLAsset* secondAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:delegate.videoURL2 options:nil];
AVURLAsset* thirdAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:delegate.videoURL3 options:nil];
if(firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil && thirdAsset!=nil){
    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    CMTime finalTime = CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration);

    //VIDEO TRACK
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *thirdTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [thirdTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, thirdAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[thirdAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:finalTime error:nil];



    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(finalTime, thirdAsset.duration));

    //FIXING ORIENTATION//
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}

    [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];


    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:secondTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *SecondAssetTrack = [[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation SecondAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;


    BOOL  isSecondAssetPortrait_  = NO;

    CGAffineTransform secondTransform = SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == 1.0 && secondTransform.c == -1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == -1.0 && secondTransform.c == 1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == 1.0)   {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(secondTransform.a == -1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == -1.0) {SecondAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *ThirdlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:thirdTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *ThirdAssetTrack = [[thirdAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation ThirdAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;


    BOOL  isThirdAssetPortrait_  = NO;

    CGAffineTransform thirdTransform = ThirdAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

    if(thirdTransform.a == 0 && thirdTransform.b == 1.0 && thirdTransform.c == -1.0 && thirdTransform.d == 0)  {ThirdAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isThirdAssetPortrait_ = YES;}

    if(thirdTransform.a == 0 && thirdTransform.b == -1.0 && thirdTransform.c == 1.0 && thirdTransform.d == 0)  {ThirdAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isThirdAssetPortrait_ = YES;}

    if(thirdTransform.a == 1.0 && thirdTransform.b == 0 && thirdTransform.c == 0 && thirdTransform.d == 1.0)   {ThirdAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(thirdTransform.a == -1.0 && thirdTransform.b == 0 && thirdTransform.c == 0 && thirdTransform.d == -1.0) {ThirdAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}


    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,SecondlayerInstruction,ThirdlayerInstruction,nil];;

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
}
```

}